# Polymer: How to get maxlength working with paper-input, as opposed to "iron-input"

Tags: html, forms, attributes, polymer-1.0

I have started trying to learn and use Polymer elements in our site. I need to only allow the users to put 4 numbers for a year so I wanted to have a `maxlength="4"` in my paper-input, but it would not work and keeps going over my maxlength limit.

```
<paper-input floatingLabel label="Please add the year in the format YYYY" name="birth_date" type="number" maxlength="4" char-counter error-message="numbers only"></paper-input>
```

However, when I put the example from [paper-input-container](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?active=paper-input-container) with `maxlength="4"`:

```
<paper-input-container>
  <label>Your name</label>
  <input is="iron-input" maxlength="4">
</paper-input-container>
```

This seems to stop the input at my maxlength, but it also uses much more code then I would like to use, as I have a decent amount of form questions for a user, as well as the fact that from the documentation and examples I have looked at, I do not see why my `maxlength` is not working in the `<paper-input>`. Am I missing something with the `paper-inputs` or am I using them wrong?

Also, if anyone knows of any good guides to form validation with polymer elements that would be much appreciated as well. Any advice is much appreciated for my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For type="number", the properties max and min can be set. To allow the user to enter only 4 characters you can set type="string" and then validate that numbers are entered using the auto-validate-pattern property.

```
<paper-input label="only type numbers (auto-validate)" auto-validate pattern="[0-9]*" error-message="numbers only!" type="string" maxlength="4"></paper-input>
```

I found the demo examples for paper-input [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-input) useful to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I have one question. I tried autoValidate, as per the documentation just as `autoValidate` before and it didn't present the error-message or turn red for the error. Do you know why in the polymer documentation it is `autoValidate`, but to actually use it in code it is `auto-validate` as you have? Seems to be the same for `charCounter` as well.

Comment: Based on this Polymer documentation on annotated event listeners [1] (https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#annotated-listeners) it seems that the syntax is on-event since the event name is specified using an HTML attribute.